# nodeJS : throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');

Tags: node.js, express

This is common SO question but didn't get the solution. So I am again putting it here.

Here is **app.js**

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
require('./routes/sockets.js').initialize(server);
```

here is **sockets.js** inside **routes** folder

```
var io = require('socket.io');
exports.initialize = function(server) {console.log('init called');
    io = io.listen(server);console.log('io');
    io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){console.log("connected");
        socket.send(JSON.stringify({type:'serverMessage',message: 'Welcome to the most interesting chat room on earth!'}));
        socket.on('message', function(message){
            message= JSON.parse(message);
            if(message.type == "userMessage")
            {
                socket.broadcast.send(JSON.stringify(message));
                message.type = "myMessage";
                socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Inside sockets.js `console.log('init called');` `console.log('io');` is printing well. When i run this app using `npm start` is got following error:

```
npm WARN package.json application-name@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json application-name@0.0.1 No readme data.

> application-name@0.0.1 start D:\Applications\New folder\node\chat
> node app.js

init called
   info  - socket.io started
io
Express server listening on port 3000
GET / 200 312ms - 511

http.js:707
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:707:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (D:\Applications\New folder\node\chat\node_m
odules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\patch.js:59:22)
    at next (D:\Applications\New folder\node\chat\node_modules\express\node_modu
les\connect\lib\proto.js:153:13)
    at Function.app.handle (D:\Applications\New folder\node\chat\node_modules\ex
press\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:198:3)
    at Server.app (D:\Applications\New folder\node\chat\node_modules\express\nod
e_modules\connect\lib\connect.js:66:31)
    at Manager.handleRequest (D:\Applications\New folder\node\chat\node_modules\
socket.io\lib\manager.js:564:28)
    at Server.<anonymous> (D:\Applications\New folder\node\chat\node_modules\soc
ket.io\lib\manager.js:118:10)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2051:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:122:23
)
```

When i access `localhost:3000` in browser all it happens. I am using node version `v0.10.10`, express `3.4.4`.

Comment: try var server = http.createServer(app); require('./routes.socket.js').initialize(server); server.listen(app.port, function(){...});

Comment: maybe in your routes you do res.end(..); or res.render(...); before sending res.send(...); Do you try to comment line require('./routes/socket.js').init(server) to see if the error come from there?

Comment: no i am not using `res` anywhere in my code. Code of routes i have posted above

Comment: if i comment out `require('./routes/sockets.js').initialize(server);` its not showing any error. means there is some problem inside `routes.js`

Comment: none of the above is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution!! It was because of some version mismatch. Here is the dependency that i used

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.4.4",
    "socket.io": "0.9",
    "jade": "*"
  }
}
```